# Count numpy array mixed data types and display in descending order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array of mixed data type: mat_resized

```
array([[25041, '40391', '5856', '5601', 'V4511', 'V5867'],    
       [25041, '40391', '25081', '5856', '5363', '3572'],    
       [25041, '40391', '42822', '99681', '5856', '2851'],    
       [25061, '40391', '5845', '2875', '3570', '2762'],    
       [25041, '40391', '2761', '5856', '25081', 'V4511'],    
       [40391, '25002', '5856', '3569', 'V4511', 'V5867']], dtype=object)
```

How can I count the occurrences, of all values within the array, and display them in descending order?

I used following codes:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(mat_resized, return_counts=True)        
counts
```

getting following error:

```
TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)    
<ipython-input-67-f9f2a0dd18c1> in <module>()    
----> 1 unique, counts = np.unique(mat_resized, return_counts=True)    
      2 counts    

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar,     return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)    
    194         aux = ar[perm]    
    195     else:    
--> 196         ar.sort()    
    197         aux = ar    
    198     flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))    

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: How do you want to sort it?

Comment: Can you just `groupby()` the original column in pandas?

Comment: @lilezek:I want these to flatten and count the number of occurrences. Columns have no significance here. All these values can occur in any order within columns. Therefore I have taken it in array and want to sort it. I am interested in filtering out the significant values based on their occurrences.

Comment: `np.sort` lets you specify field 'columns' of a structured array.  Try making this a structured array rather than an object array.

Comment: with Pandas you can use the `value_counts` method associated to `Series` as well as `sort` for a given column. It's actually not clear what you want to get at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) should work. (Because of the mixed types in your object array, `numpy.unique` won't work in Python 3; see below for a work-around.)  For example, in the following, `values` is an array containing the unique values in `a`, and `counts` is a corresponding array holding the number of times the value occurs in `a`.

```
In [31]: a
Out[31]: 
array([[123, '40381', 'V5856', 0.0],
       [456, '40381', '25081', 0.0],
       [789, 'V5856', '51851', 0.0]], dtype=object)

In [32]: values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

In [33]: values
Out[33]: array([0.0, 123, 456, 789, '25081', '40381', '51851', 'V5856'], dtype=object)

In [34]: counts
Out[34]: array([3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

To put the values in descending order by counts, use the result of `counts.argsort()` to reorder `values` and `counts`:

```
In [35]: order = counts.argsort()[::-1]

In [36]: values[order]
Out[36]: array([0.0, 'V5856', '40381', '51851', '25081', 789, 456, 123], dtype=object)

In [37]: counts[order]
Out[37]: array([3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

A work-around for Python 3 is to convert all the elements of the array to strings.  Whether or not this solves your problem depends on what you are going to do with the results of `np.unique`.

Here's the same example, using Python 3.4.3 with numpy 1.10.1:

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
array([[123, '40381', 'V5856', 0.0],
       [456, '40381', '25081', 0.0],
       [789, 'V5856', '51851', 0.0]], dtype=object)

In [24]: values, counts = np.unique(a.astype(str), return_counts=True)

In [25]: values
Out[25]: 
array(['0.0', '123', '25081', '40381', '456', '51851', '789', 'V5856'], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [26]: counts
Out[26]: array([3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])

In [27]: order = counts.argsort()[::-1]

In [28]: values[order]
Out[28]: 
array(['0.0', 'V5856', '40381', '789', '51851', '456', '25081', '123'], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [29]: counts[order]
Out[29]: array([3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Don't show error messages in comments.  They are hard to read; it is better to edit your question (clearly marked of course).

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: when I tried your array 'a', even then i am getting the same error. I am using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook. Does it have a different version of numpy (1.9)?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: I am getting this error with my array or array displayed by you above: TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: @Sanoj It worked for me with numpy 1.9.0 and 1.9.3.  Can you modify your code in the question to include a self-contained example that defines an array that causes the problem, so we can copy-and-paste the array and try to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Sanoj I was using Python 2.7.10.  I get the same error if I use python 3.4.3, with either numpy 1.9.2 or 1.10.1.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: I have python 3.4.3 with numpy 1.9. I am using Anaconda notebook for running my code. I am posting a better formatted array in my original question section with all the codes and error I am getting.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: It works. Thank you very much. I want to select important features to be used in building regression model. Array values are features.